# Problem with NearestCentroid, python, cluster

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-computing, centroid

I want to find the centroid coordinates of a cluster (list of points [x,y]). 
So, I want to use NearestCentroid() from sklearn.

```
clf = NearestCentroid()
clf.fit(X, y)
```

X : np.array of my coordinates points.

y : np.array fully filled with 1

I have an error when I launch the fit() function.

```
ValueError: y has less than 2 classes
```

Maybe there is a problem with arrays shape.
(X= (7,2) ,y= (7,))

Comment: You have only one class in your  `y`, that's why you get the error. Do you specifically need `NearestCentroid()` or  do you just want to calculate the center point of your list of points?

Comment: Ok, I understand, it's because `y` is fully filled with 1. I only want to calculate the center point of my list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The centroid of points can be calculated by summing up all the values in each dimension and averaging them. You can use `numpy.mean()` for this. Refer to the documention: [numpy.mean](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html?highlight=mean#numpy.mean)

```
import numpy as np

points = [
    [0, 0],
    [1, 1],
    [0, 1],
    [0, 100]
]
a = np.array(points)
centroid = np.mean(a, axis=0)
print(centroid)
```

Which will give:

```
[ 0.25 25.5 ]
```

You can verify this by hand. Sum up the x-axis values: `0+1+0+0 = 1` and average it: `1/4`. Same for y-axis: `0+1+1+100 = 102`, average it: `102/4 = 25.5`.

Comment: Thanks for your help